# How to remove multiple hashtags from the start of a paragraph using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to remove multiple hashtags from the beginning of a paragraph.

#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the first hashtags and keep the rest.

How should I remove the hashtags at the beginning of the paragraph?

I'm using a no-code platform to work. So there are limitations for me to write code. But I'm using the **replaceRegex** function for doing this. The platform works on javascript.

**What I have**

```
var.a = "#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags at the beginning and keep the hashtag at the center.
```

**Function**

```
{{replaceRegex var.a '/(?<! \w\s+)(#[a-zA-Z]+ *)/g' " "}}
```

**Actual Result**

```
   This is a test paragraph.  I only want to remove the hashtags at the beginning and keep the hashtag at the center.
```

**Expected Result**

```
 This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags at the beginning and keep the hashtag at the center.
```

Comment: Did the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^#[a-zA-Z]+(?: +#[a-zA-Z]+)* *
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#[a-zA-Z]+` Match `#` and 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `(?: +#[a-zA-Z]+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ spaces, `#` and 1+ chars A-Z
- `*` match optional spaces

If you want to match whitespaces you can use `\s` but note that it can also match a newline.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fROJ7l/1)

You can replace the match with an empty string.

For example using Javascript:

```js
const regex = /^#[a-zA-Z]+(?: +#[a-zA-Z]+)* */gm;
const str = `#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags at the beginning and keep the hashtag at the center.`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+\s*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WD6lid/1).

**NOTE**: If there can be any Unicode letters and you are using an ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JavaScript environment, you might use

```js
/^(?:\s*#\p{L}+)+\s*/u
```

where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\s*#[a-zA-Z]+)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `#[a-zA-Z]+` - `#` and one or more ASCII letters
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces